# Custom Control for XSL editing/development C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, controls, xslt-tools

Is there a way to use a "control" of some kind to add blocks out xsl code to an xsl file .

Example:

I frequently type these three lines of code:

```
<xsl:comment> some custom attributes and values here </xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment>#include virtual="[filepath]" </xsl:comment>
<xsl:comment> end custom tags </xsl:comment>
```

could i turn this block into some tyope of control that i could access the attributes and filepath of the include through properties?

Comment: Do you want to output different `[filepath]`? From where do you get this information, input source, parameters?

Comment: Where are you trying to use this "control"? How would you use it?

Comment: @Alejandro the file path would be to an palin html file or .inc, usually for global navigation. I used visual studio snippets which is not exactly what I was looking for but will save time and keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help.
[XSL IMPORT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_import.asp)